# Having different views and controllers on a single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using a legacy database.

I have three views and controller all having inputs into the same model, however the data is slightly different for these controllers.

When i use "prepaid" controller, the data would be in PINs and only the values are stored in the database. However if i am using a "manager" controller, the data would store the username and the pins.

I am clueless on as to how to do this and there is a lack of documentation on rails about this.

```
Radcheck Model

class Radchecks < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "radcheck"
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :username, :value, :attribute, :op, :user_id
  # alias_attribute = "attr", "attribute"
end

Managers controller 

    class ManagersController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate_user!

      def index
        @managers = Radcheck.where(user_id:current_user.id)

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @managers }
        end
      end

      def create
        @manager = Radcheck.new(radcheck_params)
        @manager.user_id = current_user.id

        respond_to do |format|
          if @manager.save
            format.html { redirect_to managers_path, notice: 'Manager has been added.' }
            format.json { render json: @manager, status: :created, location: @manager }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @manager.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    end 



  Manager view code

        <div class="span7">
         <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
             <th></th>
             <th>Username</th>
             <th>Password</th>
             <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
           <% @managers.each do |manager| %>
            <tr>
             <td><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i></td>
             <td><%= manager.username %></td>
             <td><%= manager.value %></td>
             <td>
              <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                          manager,
                          :method => :delete,
                          :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')) },
                          :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
             </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <% end %>
         </table>

        <%= link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")),
                new_manager_path,
                :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>


         </div>
```

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? is this the one you want to implement?

Comment: added more details. :)

I am trying to add Prepaids to something similar to "Managers" controller but i always end up with "Radcheck" as the button when i click on "create". Prepaids would be using random values (if you look at the model.

Comment: managers would contain the username.

Comment: @muhammadn you mentioned (in a comment, not in your question) that you always end up with "Radcheck" as the button, presumably in your view, but you don't include your view code, so we can't tell you why "Radcheck" shows up there. Sounds like though this ends up being basic refactoring; take code that's common to all 3 controllers, put it in one file, and then put the stuff specific to individual controllers in the individual files. You can have your controllers inherit from a single controller with most of the functionality.

Comment: SuperControllers and ApplicationController ?

I'll look up on that and i have added the view code. :)

Comment: @carpeliam - do you have any suggestions of a site that i can relate to with code refactoring and inheritance of the controller's functions?

I have tried looking for it all over and i am confused myself.

Comment: I now have an idea on how to go around it which is to create a module (helper) on this and create those actions within the help and call those actions from the controllers. Is it correct?

Comment: @muhammadn I think this is a basic refactoring technique, perhaps [extracting a superclass](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractSuperclass.html)? I'd recommend reading [Martin Fowler's refactoring book](http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Code/dp/0201485672/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1386372033&sr=8-1).

Comment: Simplest i can find is inherit the "Radcheck" model into "Manager" model and so is "Prepaid" model. (using Single-Table inheritance)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709257/refactoring-activerecord-models-with-a-base-class-versus-a-base-module
However, i do not know how to go about refactoring using controllers, which i may find useful in the future.

Comment: should i post a similar answer below using Single-Table Inheritance?